# Get a link to share a flag?

Tags: support, flags

I need to flag a post that I previously flagged before. My previous flag was marked as Helpful, but the behavior I brought up continues. I'd like to provide a link to the original in my new flag so that moderators can more easily see what happened before. Is there a way to get one?

I suppose I could link to my flag history, but that wouldn't show the particular flag in isolation.

Comment: Seems like a flag should exist on its own. You can say "the user has continued to do X" if you want to ask for stronger action (like a post lock).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're flagging the exact same post *again*, then your previous flag is centimeters away. When moderators see flags on posts, all the previous flags (whether they were helpful or declined) appear below the active flags in a greyed-out state, to indicate those ones are old and already handled. There's no need to "link to the flag" as you intend.

To answer your question more directly: there is no way to link to a specific flag. There's really no need to do such a thing. If a problem is persisting, you can always link to the previous post and mention you've also flagged that one before. It's extremely easy for a moderator to review flag history, as well as actions other moderators have taken on those flags (although the reasons they took those actions are not always as clear).

Comment: On a related note, user flag history apparently groups flag by post as well, so both flags are closely available there, too.

Comment: Can you provide screenshot from that interface? I'm quite curious how tools you are using looks like and what you *have to deal* with every day.